# PhpStorm Xdebug over SSH tunnel path mappings

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm debugging PHP on a remote server (Amazon Linux), using my local machine (an iMac, running MAMP Pro). I can get PhpStorm to "Break on first line", and step through execution properly, but when it moves to another file it gets totally the wrong line. It keeps stepping through and seems to be working that way, but on the wrong line so I can't really follow the code. It actually starts about 20 lines ahead of where it should.

I'm setting up an SSH tunnel from my local machine to the web server using:

```
ssh -g -N -R9000:localhost:9000 SSH_ALIAS
```

and this is great; PhpStorm picks it up and starts debugging.

I think it has something to do with path mappings. I'm debugging a command through a CLI tool that accesses the site, and its PHP files are in a separate root than the project web root (both this CLI PHP script folder and the document root for the web server are set up in PhpStorm as project root directories).

The first file, that PhpStorm is mapping correctly, is in the CLI tool's root, and the second file I'm trying to step into from the first file is in the project web root. So here's the directory structure:

`/usr/share/[CLI_TOOL_PATH]/[NAME].php` - first file's path on server
`/usr/share/[CLI_TOOL_PATH]/[NAME].php` - first file's path on local machine

`/var/www/html/main/[MODULE_PATH]` - second file's path on server
`/var/Webroot/dev_imac/[MODULE_PATH]` - second file's path on local machine

I've tried setting up a PHP server in PhpStorm for `localhost` and port `9000`, with the "Absolute path on the server" mapped to just the same path as the local files, and I've tried with the "Absolute path on the server" mapped to the actual path on the server. It might be worth noting that the CLI tool's path is exactly the same on both the local machine and the server, whereas the web root is different on both.

I've got PHP set up on the remote server with the following in php.ini:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

Hope someone can help! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's definitely a path mapping problem. The only settings you should need to change are the path mapping settings (under server settings in PHPStorm, I think).

Comment: I was thinking that! But how should I change them? I've tried the things I listed above...can't get it to work yet. What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Can you edit your post to include an example of what your directory structure looks like on your local project and on the server?

Comment: Have a look at this article in case you have not seen it yet -- may help: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Remote+debugging+in+PhpStorm+via+SSH+tunnel

Comment: Edited to include directory structure @mkasberg

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following path mappings in PHPStorm:

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| File/Directory                      | Absolute path on server          |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| /usr/share/[CLI_TOOL_PATH]          | /usr/share/[CLI_TOOL_PATH]       |
| /var/Webroot/dev_imac/[MODULE_PATH] | /var/www/html/main/[MODULE_PATH] |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Hopefully you're already set up so PHPStorm knows about those two directories on the left - it needs to recognize that they are part of the project. Normally, you'd have a project root and all your files would be subdirectories.